# Debian 7 openVZ,  unknown host

Tags: debian, openvz

Поднял openVZ на Debian 7 и из-под контейнера нет сети. К примеру:

**ping mail.ru**

```
unknown host
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

Бодался с эти вопросом сам недавно. Пример из настройки виртуального сетевого моста

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  192.168.1.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.1.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

собственно последнии 3 строки и делают проброс интернета в контейнеры с ип адресами 192.168.1.0/24

П.С. вопросы такого рода задаются в [РутКоде](http://admin.hashcode.ru/)

Comment: Виноват, в следующий раз напишу на РутКоде. 

Пока честно не разобрался, что куда из этого прописывать

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223 в /etc/network/interfaces сервера на котором стоит openVZ, после перезагрузить

Comment: решение:
vzctl set ${ID} --numothersock 120 --save
vzctl set ${ID} --nameserver 8.8.8.8 --nameserver 8.8.4.4 --save